# Bootstrap 3 Carousel Position Indicators Inners

Tags: position, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, indicator

I am new at web development and I have one maybe only for me big problem.
I tried almost everything what I can but it still doesn't working.

This is what I am looking for [IMAGE](http://www75.zippyshare.com/i/26578927/73456/image.jpg)

And this is my code

```
<div class="color"> <!-- white background with green borders -->
    <div class="all"> 

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Slider Content (Wrapper for slides )-->

            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="containter item active">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>my text ...</p>    
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="my-image_1"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>my text ...</p>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- /row -->

                </div><!-- /container item -->

    <!-- ============================================ -->

                <div class="containter item">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>my text ...</p>    
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="my-image_2"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>my text ...</p>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- /row -->

                </div><!-- /container item -->

    <!-- ============================================ -->

                <div class="containter item">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>my text ...</p>    
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="my-image_3"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>my text ...</p>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- /row -->

                </div><!-- /container item -->    

            </div> <!-- carousel-inner -->
        </div> <!-- carousel -->

    </div><!-- /all -->
</div><!-- color -->
```

And Css

```
.my-image_1 {
  background-image: url(../img/my-image_1.png);
  width: 103px;
  height:  678px;
}

.my-image_2 {
  background-image: url(../img/my-image_2.png);
  width: 113px;
  height:  678px;
}

.my-image_2 {
  background-image: url(../img/my-image_3.png);
  width: 203px;
  height:  678px;
}

.color {
  background-color: white;
  height: 590px;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

I tried to change custom  bootstrap's styles margins etc, but I had no results what I wont.

For any help I will be really grateful.

================================================================

**tchow002**

I already done this. Carousel works fine but I have problems with position indicators and white background. This is what I have [browser](http://www6.zippyshare.com/i/9941506/73504/image2.jpg)

================================================================

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your carousel.

Add this js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

Comment: I already done this. Carousel works fine but I have problems with position indicators and white background. This is what I have http://www6.zippyshare.com/i/9941506/73504/image2.jpg and this is what I wont http://www75.zippyshare.com/i/26578927/73456/image.jpg

Comment: Tell me the differences in words. I'm sure you haven't gotten your answer yet because your question isn't direct. I notice what you have has 3 indicators on the top and bottom. What you want has 4 indicators only on the top. Are you trying to remove the indicators from the bottom?

Comment: No number of indicators is not a problem. The main problem is that I wont to move indicators down and change height of white background like this http://www13.zippyshare.com/i/64394195/18/image3.jpg but when I do it with margin example .carousel-indicators {
  margin-top: -65px!important;
}

 .carousel-inner {
 margin-top: -30px!important;
 }
Than indicators doesn't work  http://www3.zippyshare.com/i/43633475/18/image4.jpg